# The package org is not accessible when importing org.bouncycastle

Tags: java, eclipse, import, ide, bouncycastle

I am encountering an issue when trying to import the Bouncy Castle library in my Java project. Despite adding the Bouncy Castle library to my project, I'm receiving the error message "The package org is not accessible" when attempting to import specific classes from the library.

```java
import org.bouncycastle.cert.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
```

Steps I've taken:

1. Verified Bouncy Castle Library: I have downloaded the Bouncy Castle JAR file and added it to my project's classpath.
2. Checked for Library Compatibility: I have added the correct version of the Bouncy Castle library that should be compatible with my project.
3. Confirmed Build Path Configuration: I have properly configured the Bouncy Castle library in my project's build path and marked it as a dependency.
4. Checked IDE Specific Configuration: I am using [insert your IDE name] and have followed the necessary steps to configure the library. However, the issue persists.
5. Cleaned and Rebuilt: I have tried cleaning my project and rebuilding it, but it did not resolve the problem.[image]

Comment: You have a module-info.java which has errors (red cross on the icon), you need to fix those (or you can stop using the Java module system by deleting the module-info.java)

Comment: `org.bouncycastle.cert(.*)` is part of bcpkix.

Comment: module Server {
requires bcprov.ext.jdk18on;
} i have this which causing an error and i need the module if i deleted it will cause an error also, so how can i make sure that the project can access  bouncy castle library

Comment: import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage; what about these? @Topaco

Comment: These all belong to the bcprov (or bcprov-ext) jar. You can find a description of the jar files in the BouncyCastle [documentation](https://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html), last section *General Documentation*, which also shows the associated packages, e.g. [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.8on/index.html) for bcprov.

Comment: In the screenshot, both referenced libraries are shown with a darker icon which means that they are visible only for test sources, but not in your source folder `src`.