# "NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException when running Java code"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, bouncycastle, noclassdeffounderror

I am encountering a `NoClassDefFoundError` with the following error message when running my Java code: `NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException`. This error occurs during runtime and indicates that the JVM cannot find the class `org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException`, which is part of the Bouncy Castle library.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYHG1.png)

I have already downloaded the Bouncy Castle library and added the JAR file to my project. However, the error persists, suggesting that the Bouncy Castle library is not being properly detected or loaded by the JVM.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRQVf.png)

Comment: You still have a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78133559/6505250) to which you have stopped responding. Your second screenshot shows two referenced libraries, but both are collapsed, so one cannot see if the missing class is contained or not.

Comment: "so one cannot see if the missing class is contained or not" what do u mean ? @howlger

Comment: Click on the `>` of `> bcpkix-jdk18on-177.jar` and of `> bcprov-ext-jdk18on-177.jar` to expand the subtree and to navigate to the missing class, if available. If you not able to find the class in one of the JARs, you have to add the right JAR containing it.

Comment: yes i can find the class its available in bcpkix

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can&apos;t be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: @aled Please stop acting as "no image of text" police as this violates the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Instead of asking for the removing of images and talking about "images of code" even if there are no images of code, ask for the text you need to answer the answer. A recent example of why screenshots are needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78133559/the-package-org-is-not-accessible-when-importing-org-bouncycastle#comment137751424_78133559

Comment: Then please update your screenshot and link to the bcpkix JAR you downloaded. Please also add the command line of your run configuration into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (indented by four spaces): in _Run > Run Configurations..._ select the run configuration and hit the _Show Command Line_ button.

Comment: @howlger: You are incorrect. We do, in fact, **not** want screenshots of code, data, and/or errors unless they are absolutely necessary. And there is, in fact, an image of an exception stacktrace in this question which is unnecessary. The link aled supplied explains why.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk There have never been images of code or images of data here. And the error is given as text. One of the two screenshots shows the error that is given as text, but also provides additional information (can you tell which?). According to the  Code of Conduct, we want collaborate in a safe and welcoming community based on kindness, cooperation and mutual respect. Instead of telling others that they are wrong, we want to help people in a professional way and tell them what they should do instead of telling them what they shouldn't do. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @Howlger: I vehemently disagree that anything aled wrote comes *in any way* close to violating the code of conduct. It's your interpretation that is wrong. aled providing a link that goes into detail about both what not to do and what to do, and his second sentence explains what to do.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Her or his second sentence is _"Copy or type the text into the question."_ The error _is_ given in the first sentence of the question. Why would you like to have it twice? Why talking about images of code and images of data even though they don't exist here? "No image of text" comments are neither helpful nor welcoming. I asked you whether you agree with the following: "Instead of telling others that they are wrong, we want to help people in a professional way and tell them what they should do instead of telling them what they shouldn't do."

Comment: @howlger: I'll not debate this any longer here. If you'd like a better community-wide discussion with folks who understand these meta issues much better than me, post a question on [Meta](meta.stackoverflow.com) and reference this question. I will leave my comments around a while longer in case you want to reference them on Meta, otherwise I'll delete them at some point today or tomorrow.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It's you who start the discussion about unrelated things (there are no images of code here, there are no images of data here, and the error is posted as text). I'm fine with the current Code of Conduct and do not want to change it to "Our mission is to tell people that they are wrong" and I'm not aware of any meta issue that calls for a "no images of text" police.